# JavaFx Finding source parent node with specific id?

Tags: javafx

Is there is the way to find parent Node ( high in hierarchy ) via method? 
Element id or class can be use.

Any alternative to something like this?

```
source.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
```

Answer (score 14):

You can lookup any Node by its ID from the Scene object.

For example:

```
Scene scene = source.getScene();
Node nodeToFind = scene.lookup("#nodeToFindId");
```

The ID is a CSS selector (id), or an FX ID. It has to be set up on the node without the '#' character. When invoking the method 'lookup', the '#' character has to precede the ID, like above.

Comment: Hm.. I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException. Maybe the problem is that I'm starting my chart like this: 
gantChartStage = new RmsGantChart(); gantChartStage.initModality(Modality.NONE); RmsGantChart extends Stage
gantChartStage.showAndWait();

Comment: Is the source Node displayed in a scene when you attempt to lookup "nodeToFindID"?

Answer (score 3):

Well I know you wanted to avoid that but still it is not that bad and does the work :

```
 Node node = youNode;
 while (node != null){
    node = node.getParent();
 }
 Node parentNode = node;
```

Otherwise if you have access to the scene object :

```
 Node parentNode = scene.getRoot();
```

Comment: if(node.getId().equals(myd) return node in while loop, and then its ok.